# Iterating Akka ByteString in reverse

Tags: scala, akka

I receive data from a TCP server as `ByteString`. A message ends with the last byte being 0x03. For every `ByteString` I receive I need to check if last byte is 0x03. Right now I am calling `lastIndexof`.

```
val data : ByteString = ...

if (data.lastIndexOf(0x03) >= 0) {}
```

But this is inefficient since for most of the message chunks it will traverse all the bytes for no good reason. Is there any way to iterate through the bytes in reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ByteString` is an `IndexedSeq`, so in constant or near constant time, you should be able to do something like this:

```
val terminated = data.lastOption.filter(_ == 0x03).getOrElse(false)
```

Under the hood, this is going to use the `apply` method to get the length - 1 element.  Both `length` and `apply` should perform in constant or near constant time according to the `IndexedSeq` documentation.

```
Indexed sequences support constant-time or near constant-time element access and length computation
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `ByteString` is a `Seq` you can do

```
if (data.last == 0x03) {}
```

But I don't how it's implemented so I can't guarantee that it doesn't traverse the whole thing anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this will work. However cmbaxter's answer is more generic and will serve me better in other problem areas. So I am accepting that one.